# Page metrics are showing up in Google analytics even though no tracking code is installed on the page?

Tags: google-analytics

In my Google analytics reports I can see pageviews on a page for which I don't have the tracking code installed for the property I'm looking at.

My site is divided in two parts - one for enterprise and one for consumers - and I have two different properties (but the same GA account) for the two sites. However, when I'm looking at the reports of the enterprise property I can see visits on the index.html page for consumers. I have double checked what tags are installed on the consumers page using the Tag Assistant in Chrome in which I can see that the only UA tag is the one for consumers. There are two remarkering tags installed on the consumers page, could that explain this behavior?

Any idea on why this page shows up in the enterprise property anyway?

Comment: Does the server have mod_pagespeed installed? This can cause your server to report the data back to the Google mothership even without the JavaScript code installed.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've tried to find out how to know that following these instruction https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache/PageSpeed#How_to_check_if_mod_pagespeed_is_already_enabled.3f . I couldn't find any "pagespeed" pieces in the script when I chose Inspect element while visiting the page but maybe that is not enough to say for certain?

Comment: Sorry, I use lighttpd for everything so I don't know much about Apache commands. On our nginx server with mod_pagespeed, I know we can use that to push google analytics code server side somehow. I assume you tried checking the full list of modules to see if pagespeed is among them?

Comment: I don't have access to the list of modules... We have outsourced all of our web development and it takes ages to get a response from our sourcing partner.

Comment: What is the referral source for these visits?

Comment: There are several referral sources, the majority is from the consumer domain (56%), 32% are direct and 2% from organic search. The rest comes from the logged on version of the enterprise site. An enterprise can include our webshop in their own web order system so that their employees can order e.g. a phone from their own internal systems, then the URL becomes something like intranet.[enterprise_name].com.